# How do I deserialize this JSON object?

Tags: python, django, json, deserialization

```
import simplejson
from urllib2 import urlopen
from simplejson import loads
from django.core import serializers
content = loads(urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/1234676502/feed').read())
content =  simplejson.dumps(content,sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print content
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
json_serializer.deserialize(content)
```

While running the above python code im getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/youedo/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 63, in get_serializer
    _load_serializers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 109, in _load_serializers
    register_serializer(format, BUILTIN_SERIALIZERS[format], serializers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 51, in register_serializer
    module = importlib.import_module(serializer_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/xml_serializer.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers import base
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 38, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

...and when I print the content it prints the JSON string correctly.

**Edit:2**
    import simplejson
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    from simplejson import loads
    from django.core import serializers
    content = loads(urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/1234676502/feed').read())

```
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
json_serializer.get_deserialize(content)
```

I put this code in my view.py then i got the following error:

```
AttributeError at /rss

'Serializer' object has no attribute 'get_deserialize'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rss
Django Version:     1.2.4
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'Serializer' object has no attribute 'get_deserialize'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error has nothing to with json per se, it clearly states that it cannot import `DJANGO_SETTINGS` which means that you do not have the django app context in place. The easiest way to go about this is install django extensions which provides the command `./manage.py runscript` which runs your script with your django app context.

[Django extensions can be found here](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)

**Edit:**: looking at your second edit, I can see that you are using a method `get_deserialize()`, the right method should be `deserialize()`, AFAIK.

Comment: I changed it then i am getting this error "type object 'Serializer' has no attribute 'deserialize'"